# jsx: ReactJS if condition

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

How to use if condition in jsx: ReactJS? I just want that if the

```
if user == "author" or "supervisor":
<IconButton 
   aria-label="delete" 
   onClick={() => props.pressHandler(props.id)}
 >
  <DeleteIcon style={{ color: 'red' }} />
</IconButton>
else
     no delete button
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put them in braces,

```
{ ["author", "supervisor"].includes(user) &&
<IconButton 
   aria-label="delete" 
   onClick={() => props.pressHandler(props.id)}
 >
  <DeleteIcon style={{ color: 'red' }} />
</IconButton> || null }
```

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on what Stark wrote:

You can use the js operator as such:

```
{(
 (user === "author" || user === "supervisor") && 
<IconButton 
   aria-label="delete" 
   onClick={() => props.pressHandler(props.id)}
 >
  <DeleteIcon style={{ color: 'red' }} />
</IconButton>
) || undefined
}
```

Same above with ternary operator and React Fragment:

```
{
(user === "author" || user === "supervisor") ?
<IconButton 
   aria-label="delete" 
   onClick={() => props.pressHandler(props.id)}
 >
  <DeleteIcon style={{ color: 'red' }} />
</IconButton> : <></>
}
```

In false case, `Undefined` or `React.Fragment` wont be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  ["author", "supervisor"].includes(user) ? (
    <IconButton
      aria-label="delete"
      onClick={() => props.pressHandler(props.id)}
    >
      <DeleteIcon style={{ color: "red" }} />
    </IconButton>
  ) : null;
}
```

When you use "&&" operator sometimes you can see "false" text  on your app. null will be great option to display nothing or use can put something  differrent than delete button for regular user as null.